# Trouble making a project with Maven

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, project

I was able to install Maven on my system (i.e. mvn --version returns the right result). However, I get an error when I try to build a project with mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false. I am including a screenshot of the error as an image[Maven error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bxiS.png). I can't seem to find the pom.xml file to target a Java version. Where is the pom.xml file after I installed Maven? I have the latest version of Maven. Thank you.

I was able to install Maven, however, I followed the instructions on the site https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html for creating a project and it didn't work.

Comment: This is not about a pom file - the pom will be created by the `archetype:generate`. The `IOException` has a different cause. Your command works fine on my machine. Can you try running this command in a folder without spaces? The space in "Program Files" has caused some issues for me in the past too.

Comment: Ok it worked in a different folder